# How to use strapi upload plugin inside code in version 3.1.6?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, content-management-system, koa, strapi

In version 3.0.0-beta.18 I used this :

```
const buffers = await uploadService.bufferize(files.attachment);
  await uploadService.upload(buffers, config);
```

to download files. And now I have switched to 3.1.6 and this method returns an error:

```
===Error===
 TypeError: uploadService.bufferize is not a function
```

I try to use `streamToBuffer` but it doesn't work